# How Can I use components using CDN in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am using vue.js as CDN. I need help with a schematic of how I can build an application to display the component in index.html. Currently, I have the following structure:

```
<div id="app">

</div>
<script>
const { createApp } = Vue
createApp({

  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

component.js:

```
<template>
   <div>
      Test
   </div>
</template>


export default {
    data: () => ({
    }),
 
   
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to define Vue and use `.component`

```js
//in other file
const component1 = {
  template: `<div> {{ item }} <p>{{ prop }}</p></div>`,
  props: ['prop'],
  data: () => ({ item: 'test' }),
}


const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({ someData: 'prop' }),
})
app.component('test', component1)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test :prop="someData" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can I store components in other file?

Comment: @Svetlana Goodman hey, I never tried, but you can, create components as objects `const component1 = {
  template: <div> Test </div, data: () => ({ }),})` in other files, in file where you define Vue  and use `app.component('test', component1)`

Comment: Hey, Im just asking because my template are going to be well-structured, I mean - a lot of methods and lines of code, so thats why I wonder if there is any way to store components in other files.

Comment: A bit late but you can separate it into different files: you can use this:
`const test = {
template: <div>hi<div>,
};
export const test;`
Then make sure to import them in your main.js file
import Test from './components/test.js'`

Then inside your app div on index.html you can use <test/>

Answer (score 2):

**component_one.html**

```html
<p>component one</p>
```

**component_two.html**

```html
<p>component {{two}}</p>
<input type="text" v-model="two"/>
```

**component_three.html**

```html
<p>component three</p>
```

**app.html**

```html
<router-link to="/">one</router-link> | 
<router-link to="/two">two</router-link>
<component_three/>
<router-view />
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.41/vue.global.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/4.1.6/vue-router.global.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
const one = async () => {
    let template = await fetch("component_one.html")
    template = await template.text()
    return ({
        template: template,
        setup() {/*...*/ }
    })
}

const two = async () => {
    let template = await fetch("component_two.html")
    template = await template.text()
    return ({
        template: template,
        setup() {
            return {
                two: Vue.ref("TWO"),
            }
        }
    })
}

const three = async () => {
    let template = await fetch("component_three.html")
    template = await template.text()
    return ({
        template: template,
        setup() {/*...*/ }
    })
}

const app = async () => {
    let template = await fetch("app.html")
    template = await template.text()
    return ({
        template: template,
        components: {
            "component_three" : await three(),
        },
        setup() {/*...*/ }
    })
}

const init = async () => {
    const index = Vue.createApp(await app());       
    const routings = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history : VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
        routes : [
            {path:'/', component: await one()},
            {path:'/two', component: await two()}
        ]
    })
    index.use(routings)
    index.mount("#app")
}

init()
```

html files are read as string. maybe put them in backend/database server. For faster loading, use `Promise.all([])` to all await components.
working example: [www.julven.epizy.com/vuetest](http://www.julven.epizy.com/vuetest)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have tried with vue router. We can separate the logic to components.
[Here is the example in replit](https://replit.com/@wongman2/vueCdnDemo#index.html)

In the **index.html**, we can use the `<script type="module">` so we can use the import the js files.

In the **components/home/home.js**,
importTemplate function accepts a html file path and return the html file as string.
Other vue properties like methods, data can be put in the `export default {}`.

If sub-components are needed, we can use `app.component('bottomb', BottomBar)` like the one in index.html. `<bottomb />` can then be used in **all other components** like the home.html, not just in index.html.