# Vue3 Do I have to use SPA or CDN?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, single-page-application, cdn

I looked over the vue3 documents. and found out that I can start vue3 not only using npm but also embedding cdn script tag into html file.

I checked out the post here [How Can I use components using CDN in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637154/how-can-i-use-components-using-cdn-in-vue-js) and CDN can also use components.

When it comes to using components SPA is generally better than CDN? I am asking about general tendency. I know that there is no absloute single solution. because we are in different situations.

For my case I have about 20 HTML files if I have to use CDN embedded into HTML. and sidebar, header parts are common for every HTML pages. and on average the specific parts are used in around 5-7 HTML files.

In my opinion, I think using SPA would be better than CDN in this case.

1. When I use SPA I can easily create common component part as a single vue file.
2. If I use CDN vue I cannot use npm package manager, which provieds more vue-friendly libraries than cdn imported libraries.

Can you verify my statement please?

Comment: duplicated question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637154/how-can-i-use-components-using-cdn-in-vue-js

Comment: @MuhammadIchsan edited my question!

Comment: "For my case I have about 20 HTML files" - this isn't SPA, it stands for single page app. Unless you use these htmls to load the same app for some reason. 1 - no, it's about not being able to use .vue files for components and other restrictions. 2 - technically you can use npm and copy node_modules to a server and load scripts from it, this isn't different from loading scripts from CDNs, just more messy. Vue CDN is for prototyping in short but limited and probably unclean way, it's not directly related to SPA/MPA difference, although it may be easier to integrate it to framework-unfriendly MPA

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes! 20 HTML files logically fall into a single category. It can be integrated into a single app. Can you elaborate more on reason #1? and for #2, so I can still use npm modules when using CDN, but It would be incovenient than SPA?

Comment: Vue with build tools is a default way to use it. "Vue CDN" approach is limited and you won't be able to use .vue format and some other things, you'll need to figure out on your own how to make it work because the docs on the web cover only the first case. Some third-party libraries don't support "Vue CDN" at all. You can upload node_modules and use <script src="/node_modules/whatever-package/dist/bundle.umd.js">, as long as a package provides UMD module that supports this use, which is not always the case

Comment: Thanks.  It helped me a lot to appeal my statement!